# Restricting page url to be opened into another by simply copying and pasting

Tags: c#-2.0

When i Copy my url after logging into another browser it displays the same page instead of login page .This happens even after i close my page

Comment: Please clarify your question. You are copying your URL from what into where?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your session handling. The session ID should not show up in the URL (or at least not be used *alone* for authorization of the request).